# Strange window opening when opening an app through the terminal with i3wm

Tags: ubuntu, i3-window-manager, i3

I recently installed i3 and so far I'm loving it.

There is just one small thing that still put me off: when I open an application through the terminal (I tried with the default Gnome terminal and Xterm), it opens the application and a strange window (the screenshot provided is when I opened vsCode, but the issue is similar with Firefox for example)
It does not take much time to close it (especially with i3 shortcuts) but it is still a little annoyance that I'd love to get rid of...

From what I've found online (I couldn't find anyone that has the same problem... but I might not have looked at the right place just because I don't know for sure what this window is), I think that this Window is GTK Inspector...

When I switch to my default Firefox profile, the issue disappears. I searched through my config files and I find no mention of GTK something.

The window closes as soon as I exit the app I opened.
Using wmctrl -l doesn't show this strange window.

[screenshot of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFPKJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing GTK_DEBUG=interactive in ~/.bashrc